# Implementing ReentrantReadWriteLock using ReentrantLock

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, locking

I'm looking for a way to implement a **multi-read exclusive-write** synchronizer, without using ReentrantReadWriteLock.

These are the two methods that I wrote:

```
public int getDiff() {
    boolean isCurrentThread = false; // does the current thread hold readLock
    if (!readLock.isLocked()) {
        readLock.lock();
        isCurrentThread = true;
    }
    while (writeLock.isLocked());
    try {
        return Math.abs(x - y);
    } finally {
        if (isCurrentThread)
            readLock.unlock();
    }
}

public void update(int dx, int dy) {
    writeLock.lock();
    readLock.lock();
    try {
        x = x + dx;
        y = y + dy;
    } finally {
        writeLock.unlock();
        readLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

`readLock`, `writeLock` are ReentrantLock properties. `x`, `y` are integers.

The while loop in `getDiff` doesn't seem right, but I couldn't think of any other solution.

Also, how can I debug this code?

Comment: Can you give the reason why you can't or won't use `ReentrantReadWriteLock`?

Comment: It is not allowed in the assignment, so I wrote an alternative solution and now I want to know how good it is.

Comment: The busy-waiting (the while loop) definitely needs improvement. If you want to wait for the write lock to be released, why not lock and immediately unlock it?